# Display Product Attributes color,size,package in Order Grid Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.8, adminhtml

I have created a custom module using "Renderer" in the Order Grid of Magento. 
I made a file named app/code/local/Od/Ordergridproduct/Block/Adminhtml/Renderer/ProductDetail.php
and here is my code:

```
<?php
class Od_Ordergridproduct_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_ProductDetail extends     Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {

        $order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($row['entity_id']);
        $str="";
        $i=1;
        foreach($order->getAllItems() as $_order){
            $str.="<b>".$_order->getProduct()->getName()."</b>";
            $str.= "<br><b>Product Code:</b><br>".$_order->getSku();
            if($i!=count($order->getAllItems()))
                $str.=", ";
                $i++;
    }
        $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($row['entity_id']);

        $color_att = $_product->getAttributeText('color'));
        $size_att = $_product->getAttributeText('size'));
        $package_att = $_product->getAttributeText('package'));
        $str.= "<br><b>Product Color:</b><br>".$color_att;
        $str.= "<br><b>Product Package:</b><br>".$color_package;

        unset($order);
        return $str;
    }
}
```

I have got the product name but I need to display product attributes (color,brand, ,size,package) in same column to the grid. I tried adding below lines on my code

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($row['entity_id']);

    $color_att = $_product->getAttributeText('color'));
    $size_att = $_product->getAttributeText('size'));
    $package_att = $_product->getAttributeText('package'));
    $str.= "<br><b>Product Color:</b><br>".$color_att;
    $str.= "<br><b>Product Package:</b><br>".$color_package;
```

but could not figure out any thing. Anybody can help me? Hoping for positive response.

Answer (score 0):

$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($row['entity_id']);

this is wrong code b/z here $row['entity_id'] is order id not product id

```
public function render(Varien_Object $row)
   {

       $order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($row['entity_id']);
       $str="";
       $i=1;
       foreach($order->getAllItems() as $_order){
           $str.="<b>".$_order->getProduct()->getName()."</b>";
           $str.= "<br><b>Product Code:</b><br>".$_order->getSku();
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_order->getProductId());
$color_att = $_product->getAttributeText('color'));
$size_att = $_product->getAttributeText('size'));
$package_att = $_product->getAttributeText('package'));
$str.= "<br><b>Product Color:</b><br>".$color_att;
$str.= "<br><b>Product Package:</b><br>".$color_package;

           if($i!=count($order->getAllItems()))
               $str.=", ";

               $i++;
}

       unset($order);
       return $str;
   }
```

Comment: I didn't get the color by using your given code. Attributes size,package,color is empty by using this line $_product->getAttributeText('color').

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer. Now I can Display Product Attributes color,size,package in Sales Order Grid. Here is the code:

```
public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {

       $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($row['entity_id']);
       $_items = $order->getItemsCollection();
       $str="";
       $i=1;
       foreach($_items as $item){
            if ($item->getParentItem()) continue;
            $str.="<b>".$item->getName()."</b><br>";
            $str.= "<br><b>Product Code:</b><br>".$item->getSku()."<br>";


       }
       foreach($order->getAllItems() as $_order){
            $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_order->getProductId());
            $size_att = $_product->getAttributeText('size');
            $package_att = $_product->getAttributeText('package');
            if(!empty($size_att))
                $str.= "<br><b>Package Contains:</b><br>".$package_att."<br>";
            if(!empty($package_att))
            $str.= "<br><b>Size:</b><br>".$size_att."<br>";


        }
        $items = $order->getAllItems();
        $block = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('sales/order_item_renderer_default');
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $block->setItem($item);
            $_options = $block->getItemOptions();
            foreach ($_options as $option) {
                $label = $option['label'];
                $textValue = $option['print_value'];
                if(!empty($textValue))
                    $str.= "<br><b>Color:</b><br>".$textValue."<br>";
            }
        }

       unset($order);
       return $str;
   }
```